# Building kernel modules for different linux version

Tags: module, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I am new to writing kernel modules, so facing few non-technical problems.

Since for creating kernel module for a specific kernel version ( say 3.0.0-10, 10 is patch number) requires same version kernel headers, so it looks straight to install kernel headers and start development over there.
 But kernel headers for patched kernel version are not available.
As I have a guest kernel vmlinuz-3.0.0-10 running in machine and upon downloading kernel headers it says not found.

- other approach is to get the source for that specific kernel, but again problem is same source for patched kernel is not available ( its not necessary to get sources of linux-kernel-3.0.0-10 or even linux-kernel-3.0.0 and 10th patch). In some situation it is possible to get source of running kernel, but not always possible.
- another is to build kernel other than the running kernel and place built kernel in the machine. But it requires to build the modules of that kernel that is time-consuming and space-consuming process.

So intention of asking this is to know what are the preferences of kernel driver developers. Are there other alternatives ?

Is it possible to compile kernel module in one version and run in another version ( though it is going to give error, but are there any workaround for this ?)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So, building a new kernel is not a good option as it will require :

- building kernel
- building modules and firmware
- building headers
  Moving all of above things in appropriate location (if your machine is not same on which you are going to develop module)

So if you have kernel headers for running system then you dont need to download a source code for any kernel version, and while making module use

```
make -C /lib/modules/kernel-headers-x.y.z/build M=`pwd` modules
```

and your module will be ready.

If there would be better answers, i will not hesitate to accept any of them.

Comment: After go to module source code -> My command: make -C /androidsourcecode/common M='pwd' modules  -------- Error:::::::::::: WARNING: Symbol version dump /androidsourcecode/common/Module.symvers is missing; modules will have no dependencies and modversions.--------scripts/Makefile.build:44 /androidsourcecode/common/pwd/Makefile: No such file or directory

Answer (score 3):

I know it's a long time since this question asked. I am new in the kernel development. I have also encountered the same error. But now I am able to load my module in the different kernel by which I have built it. Following is the solution:

1. download the kernel-devel related to the image that you are running. It should have version as close as possible.
2. Check that the functions you are using in the module are mapped with the header files you have in the kernel-devel.
3. change the *include/generated/utsrelease.h* file for UTS_RELEASE value. change it to the version of kernel image running on your HW.
4. Compile the module using this kernel tree.
5. Now you can insert your module inside kernel.

Note:: It may cause some unwanted events to be happened as Shahbaz mentioned above. But if you are doing this just for experiments I think its good to go. :)

Answer (score -6):

There is a way to build a module on one kernel and insert it in another. It is by turning off a certain configuration. I am not telling you which configuration it is because this is ABSOLUTELY DANGEROUS. The reason is that there may be changes between the kernels that could cause your module to behave differently, often resulting in a total freeze.

What you should do is to build the module against an already-built kernel (or at least a configured one). If you have a patched kernel, the best thing you can do is to build that kernel and boot your OS with that.

I know this is time consuming. I have done it many many times and I know how boring it can get, but once you do it right, it makes your life much easier. Kernel compilation takes about 2 hours or so, but you can parallelize it if you have a multi-core CPU. Also, you can always let it compile before you leave the office (or if at home, before going to bed) and let it work at night.

In short, I strongly recommend that you build the kernel you are interested in yourself.

Comment: I am also looking for that way "It is by turning off a certain configuration", since without doing it I will not be able to know what is so dangerous. So can you share the details

Comment: You sound like you are trying to fool me into giving you the simple answer because you really don't care about the danger. Well I for one refuse to teach you anything bad.

Comment: If you are interested in knowing the danger, here it is. If a certain constant in the kernel changes value, when you use that constant in another kernel the function may do a different thing. Worse than that, if a function signature changes, they expect different arguments in the stack than your code puts. That means writing all over the stack, random return addresses and total disaster. It can also happen that a function in one version performs a certain necessary action that in another does it somewhere else. Your code would miss that functionality and again, disaster.

Comment: speaking about symbols ? fyi I am going to do all these experiments inside a VM, so my native machine is not bothered about kernel panics and oops. :-)

Comment: It's really unlikely for a kernel panic or random freezes to actually damage your computer. It's the fact that your linux crashes which is the problem. I have a question though, do you have this patched kernel available or not? If you do, why don't you just use that? If not, how are you going to test loading a module on it?

Comment: module building problem was not specific to that kernel. I took an example. because when i started to write an hello world kernel module, i found that my vm has 3.0.0-10, whose headers I am unlikely to get from anywhere. and my host machine is also 2.6.35-22 (though kernel headers for this are available). So I think this is a general problem.

Comment: How can I build module for android linux kernel 3.0.50, while my compiler linux kernel is 3.13 ?!!!!

Comment: @mr.hyde, did you see the accepted answer? Try asking a new question if that doesn't work for you, because this question is kind of different.

Comment: @Shahbaz I did. After go to module source code -> My command: make -C /androidsourcecode/common M='pwd' modules  -------- Error:::::::::::: WARNING: Symbol version dump /androidsourcecode/common/Module.symvers is missing; modules will have no dependencies and modversions.--------scripts/Makefile.build:44 /androidsourcecode/common/pwd/Makefile: No such file or directory