# Linux Kernel Modules between different kernel patches

Tags: linux, module, kernel

I am running into a issue with RH7 kernels. We are running RH6/Centos6 based systems - we normally compile the kernel module once (Centos6.6) and we could install the kernel module on another Centos kernel in the same series (say Centos6.4).

With Centos7 (3.10 kernel) I cannot build the kernel module with says 3.10.0-329 (Centos7.2) kernel and install on a kernel version 3.10.0-227 (Centos7.1) - insmod returns invalid format.

Anyone run into similar issues - are there any workarounds. 
Thanks

--
Jimmy

Comment: It is normal that module built for one kernel doesn't work for another kernel, see e.g. [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10861872/building-kernel-modules-for-linux-differnet-version). `insmod` has some protection against loading unsuitable modules, and generally hacking this check is not a good idea. You have to build module for every kernel on which you want to use it. If it is OK for you to deliver module's sources, you may use `dkms` for automatically build and install them on target machine for every needed kernel.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The problem is I cannot distribute all the sources for the module. I was thinking of the dkms option. But compiling my module partially and compiling the a partial driver which will include the rest of the module. Not even sure if this is possible.

Comment: Probably, you want a *binary blob* - ready-made object file which is part of the module. Look into [kernel documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kbuild/modules.txt) for know how to build module which uses binary blobs.

Comment: Thanks for the link. That is exactly what I was going to do.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, you want a *binary blob* - ready-made object file which is part of the module. Look into [kernel documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kbuild/modules.txt) for know how to build module which uses binary blobs. – Tsyvarev