# Building an old kernel module on latest kernel

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, kernel-module, network-protocols

CLNP ( Connection Less Network protocol ) was present as a loadable kernel module in 2.6.17.3 linux version.
At that time it was not linked with Datalink layer and Application layer and so the project was not considered as complete.

The project of implementing CLNP was continued by the CLNP sub­team of BPPT­-SGU 2008 and the remaining work was also completed.

Here is the source code for it.

https://github.com/crazoes/clnp

INSTALL file gives the description about how we can load this particular module in 2.6.17.3 kernel as it has slight different process than other modules. https://github.com/crazoes/clnp/blob/test/INSTALL

***My Question***

I want to load this module on the current kernel version. Is this possible?

My ultimate goal is to anyhow get this module working on latest kernel version. But this doesn't seem to be possible without changing the code. I am assuming that I'll have to rework on the whole driver.
Because many of the header files which CLNP was using during 2.6.17.3 kernel version (example:- socket.h) has changed in lot of terms.

But still, I would like to know if there is any way possible to have this work done.

Comment: "I would like to know if there is any way possible to have this work done." - For run an old code on the new kernel, there is no other way than rewritting the code. You may do that manually, or try to find the appropriate patch.

Comment: @Tsyvarev thanks for your answer. Is there a way as given in the following link's question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10861872/building-kernel-modules-for-different-linux-version). If we can do this by having the headers of 2.6.17.3? I am not sure about this.

Comment: It is unlikely that a code, compiled agaist such old headers, will fit for the new kernel.